# Angular - Child routing not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router

**EDIT SOLUTION:**

I ended up having to navigate by using something like this (which differs slightly from the code below)

```
  onSelect(menuItem: string): void {
    this.selectedMenuItem = menuItem;
    if (menuItem == 'Upload') {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/adminhome/(adminhomeviewport:adminupload)');
    }
    else if (menuItem == "Download") {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/adminhome/(adminhomeviewport:admindownload)');
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure why it has to be done this way, or why if there is another way to do it, but this gives me the expected behavior.

I'm using Angular and I'm trying to have a named router-outlet in one of my views.  Unfortunately, nothing seems to be working at all.  My goal is to get the router-outlet named 'admin-viewport' found on the 'http://localhost:4200/adminhome' page to show the 'AdminUploadComponent' and it's related view.

As of now, the parent html, http://localhost:4200/adminhome, which I can successfully navigate to looks like this:

```
<div class="home-root">
  <ul class="home-menu"  ng-controller="AdminHomeComponent">
    <li *ngFor="let menuString of menuStrings"
        [class.selected]="menuString === selectedMenuItem"
        (click)="onSelect(menuString)">
      <span class="badge">*</span>{{menuString}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  <router-outlet name="admin-viewport"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And the routes in my app.module.ts looks like this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
{
  path: 'adminlogin',
  component: AdminLoginComponent
},
{
  path: 'search',
  component: SearchQueryComponent
},
{
  path: 'adminhome',
  component: AdminHomeComponent,
  children : [
    {
      path: 'adminupload',
      component: AdminUploadComponent,
      outlet: 'admin-viewport'
    },
  ]
}
```

],
  { enableTracing: true }
)

On a button click, I attempt to navigate my outlet using this code.:

```
  constructor( private router: Router,public route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  onSelect(menuItem: string): void {
    this.selectedMenuItem = menuItem;
    if( menuItem == 'Upload' )
    {
      this.router.navigate(['/adminhome/adminupload', {outlet : 'admin-viewport'}]);
    }
  }
```

Which of course throws the following error:

```
error_handler.ts:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'adminhome/adminupload;outlet=admin-viewport'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'adminhome/adminupload;outlet=admin-viewport'
```

Any help on how to navigate my child router-outlet would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: When I list my routes after implementing @Seejatheran's suggestion, it still doesn't work and I get this this when I list my paths.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define another path under children,

```
{
  path: 'adminhome',
  component: AdminHomeComponent,
  children : [
    {
      path: 'adminupload',
      component: AdminUploadComponent,
      outlet: 'admin-viewport'
    },
    {
      path: 'adminupload',
      component: AdminUploadComponent,
      outlet: 'admin-viewport/:type'
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onSelect method try this :

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { admin-viewport: ['adminupload'] } }]);
```

Hope this helps